# Join multiple detail tables with different design to master table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, select

```
TABLE_MASTER
  ID Value
---- ----------
   1 MasterValue_1
   2 MasterValue_2

TABLE_DETAIL1
  ID MASTERID Value       DATE
---- -------- ----------- --------
   1 1        SubValue1_1 01.01.2014
   2 1        SubValue1_2 01.01.2014

TABLE_DETAIL2
  ID MASTERID ValueX      DATE
---- -------- ----------- --------
   3 1        SubValue2_1 01.01.2014
   4 1        SubValue2_2 01.01.2013
```

Now I want to determine the detail tables and the columns **Value** and **ValueX** in one Select
But I need to know which detail is selected

Sample-Select:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_MASTER n
INNER JOIN TABLE_DETAIL1 d1 ON d1.ID = m.ID
INNER JOIN TABLE_DETAIL2 d2 ON d2.ID = m.ID
WHERE d1.DATE >= GETDATE() OR d2.DATE >= GETDATE()
```

Result is something like that:

```
  ID Value           ID MASTERID Value       DATE       ID MASTERID ValueX      DATE
---- ------------- ---- -------- ----------- -------- ---- -------- ----------- --------
   1 MasterValue_1  1   1        SubValue1_1 01.01.2014  3 1        SubValue2_1 01.01.2014
   ***
   ***
```

I need something like an **CASE WHICH JOIN** or so

```
  ID Value         DETAILID Value       DATE    
---- ------------- -------- ----------- -------- 
   1 MasterValue_1     1    SubValue1_1 01.01.2014
   1 MasterValue_1     2    SubValue1_2 01.01.2014
   1 MasterValue_1     3    SubValue2_1 01.01.2014
```

the best solution is one which I can use on mssql AND oracle

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: yeah its difficult to explain. my desired output ist the last code block which I have posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work on both Oracle and SQL Server (though you'll need to wrap some column names that uses keywords with properly column identifiers):

```
SELECT  M.ID,
        M.Value,
        D.ID DETAILID,
        D.Value DetailValue,
        D.Date
FROM TABLE_MASTER M
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM TABLE_DETAIL1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT *
            FROM TABLE_DETAIL2) D
    ON M.ID = D.MASTER_ID
```

Comment: great! with the modification of INNER JOIN this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This works on SQl Server and I know UNION ALL is part of the SQL standard so something close should work on Oracle. Note - possible I made minor syntax error since I don't actually have these tables to play with, but this is the idea.

```
SELECT m.ID, m.Value.d1.ID as DetailID,d1.Value as DetailValue,d1.DATE as DATE
FROM TABLE_MASTER m
INNER JOIN TABLE_DETAIL1 d1 ON m.ID = d1.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT m.ID, m.Value.d2.ID as DetailID,d2.ValueX as DetailValue,d2.DATE as DATE
FROM TABLE_MASTER m
INNER JOIN TABLE_DETAIL2 d2 ON m.ID = d2.ID
```

Comment: thanks your statement looks good too. Lamak was a little bit faste and I implemented his version. But you get an upvote too.